# Best practice to ajax call for multiple form in WordPress

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, wordpress

In the WordPress site, I have multiple forms and for that, I need to write multiple jQuery/Ajax call like below:

**To update Account settings;**

```
 $("#account_form").on('submit', function(){        
    var _ajax_nonce = th.nonce_account_form;
    var action = 'nonce_account_form_action';
    var data = $(this).serialize();
    var form_data = '_ajax_nonce=' + _ajax_nonce + '&action=' + action + '&' + data;

    $.ajax({
        url : th.ajaxurl,
        type : 'POST',
        dataType : 'json',
        data : form_data,
        beforeSend : function(){
            $("#account_form_ajax_result").html(th.wait);
        }, 
        success : function(result){                
            console.log(result);
            $("#account_form_ajax_result").html(result.data);                
        }
    });        
    return false;
});
```

**To update billing settings;**

```
$("#billing_form").on('submit', function(){  
  // ....
});
```

and so on.....

Now, my question'**s** is ---

1) Is it best practice to use multiple jQuery/Ajax call like what I am doing now?
2) If no, then how can I use one jQuery/Ajax call for all forms?
3) Is that above jQuery/Ajax code is secure enough?

**For that PHP part I am using below code:**

```
function ajax_account_form()
{
    // Check nonce first
    check_ajax_referer('nonce_account_form_action');
}
```

Comment: Provided the form is set up correctly, all the information for the ajax call is available. The URL is in the `action` attribute, GET/POST is in the `method` attribute, and the form data is in the form inputs. Add hidden ones for your nonce, etc, that way you also don't have to compose a query string manually. If you do this, you can use a single submit handler that pulls all the info from the form itself.

Comment: make your ajax method general and whatever is different in different forms just add theme to params to that general method. Next is a fine method to use ajax.